# How to call arguments in Godot engine?

Tags: arguments, godot, gdscript

I am trying to make gravity for my character, but I can't use `is_on_floor()` without calling `move_and_slide()`. How do I call `move_and_slide()` in GDscript?

Comment: You should be able to call `is_on_floor()` directly on your object, as long as it's a KinematicBody or KinematicBody2D. Can you post your code? Including the part that says "extends" at the top?

Comment: extends KinematicBody2D

var motion = Vector2()
var gravity = -10
var speed = 1
var aceleration = 3

func _process(delta):
 
 if not is_on_floor():
  position.y += gravity
  
 
 if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
  position.x += speed
  
  
 if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
  position.x += -speed

Answer (score 0):

The `is_on_floor()`, `is_on_wall()`, `is_on_ceiling()`, or `get_slide_count()` functions only have context when you are moving the KinematicBody2D with `move_and_slide()` or `move_and_slide_with_snap()`.  If not, they will return `false` or `0` because they are never updated correctly.

The Godot documentation explains how to use these functions very well:

[Using KinematicBody2D Godot Documentation](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/physics/using_kinematic_body_2d.html)

The 2d platformer demo is a good reference for implementing these functions in a real world use case (a little more complicated).  It uses `move_and_slide_with_snap`, but very similar logic applies.  Here is the link:

[Godot 2D Platformer Demo](https://github.com/godotengine/godot-demo-projects/tree/master/2d/platformer)